# Making socket.listen listen for more than 5 clients

Tags: python, sockets

I am making a game server using socket, but I saw that the max connections I can get is 5 clients. How do I receive connections from more than 5 people? for an example:

```
socket.listen(1000)
```

Every time I put the integer over than 5, I wouldn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number in listen is the length of the incoming-connection-queue. It is only used when a client connects to the server. As soon as the server accepts the connection, there is a free slot in the queue again. You can have a much larger number of active connections.

Comment: I did not understand your answer. What do you mean by incoming-connection-queue? Please simplify your answer.

Comment: @user3167683 Make up your mind. Either you want further information *or* a simpler answer. And if you don't understand the answer why have you accepted it?

Comment: @EJP I just had a misunderstanding about the socket.listen. I confused it with how many clients can a server handle at once. Thank you.